# T.test in R program for multiple data sets

Tags: r

So I know that R has a built in function for t.test....which is basically just t.test(y1,y2) etc
But I'm having trouble accessing the data I wish to compare.

So I basically have two seperate data outputs
The first one is just called 'data' and it has an output similar to this

```
Time    Kilometres
0   0
1   0.05
2   0.1
3   0.15
4   0.2
5   0.25
6   0.3
7   0.35
8   0.4
9   0.45
10  0.5
```

The other output is called 'hunt' and has this output

```
cuts: [20,25)
   Time Kilometres
21   20        7.3
22   21        8.4
23   22        9.5
24   23       10.6
25   24       11.7
------------------------------------------------------------ 
cuts: [25,30)
   Time Kilometres
26   25       12.8
27   26       13.9
28   27       15.0
29   28       16.1
30   29       17.2
------------------------------------------------------------ 
cuts: [30,35)
   Time Kilometres
31   30       18.3
32   31       19.4
33   32       20.5
34   33       21.6
35   34       22.7
```

My question is, would it be possible to do seperate T.tests for each cut. Like get seperate p values for each cut whilst comparing each cut with my first data called 'data'.

so the p value for cuts:[0,5] =
                   cuts:[5:10] = 
etc
Thanks again

Comment: I know it's not what you asked, but have you considered using ANOVA instead? You could use Tukey's  test to compare between treatments.

Comment: Thats cool...sorry I'm blank on statistics....but would that give me seperate p values as well...?

Comment: If you're not versed in statistics, perhaps you could seek out local help from a statistician.

Answer (score 0):

So far it is not clear what you want to test within each group. The `t.test` can be used as either a two-group test or a one group test. You have only one group per cut. When used as a one-group test, there needs to be an assumed value for the mean against which the test gets run, but it's not clear what sort of reference value would be appropriate. I'm wondering if what you really want to do is a linear regression within each cut-category to test for a trend? This would implicitly be testing against a slope of zero. This is lightly tested code:

```
 lapply( split( dat, cut.grp) , 
         function(dgrp) summary(lm( Kilometres ~ Time, data=dgrp))$coefficients [ ,"Pr(>|t|)"] )
```